# Is it possible to do API streaming using curl library similar to python's request (or some other C++ lib)?

Tags: c++, c, curl, python-requests

I have a python test script that performs an API streaming using `requests.post()`. It looks like so:

```py
response = requests.post(url_events, data="XYZ", stream=True, headers = {"A":"B"})
if (response.ok):
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
        print chunk
```

I'm trying to figure out how can I have the same logic but using C++. From what I found the `curl` library may help, however I cannot find how to pass `data` field. This is the code I have so far:

```cpp
CURL* connection = curl_easy_init();
// set url
curl_easy_setopt(connection, CURLOPT_URL, url_events);

// set header
struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "A:B");
code = curl_easy_setopt(connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

// set streaming callback that will print every received message
curl_easy_setopt(connection, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, printCallback);

// start connection
code = curl_easy_perform(connection);
// ... 
curl_easy_cleanup(connection);
curl_slist_free_all(headers);
```

I was looking through the `curl.h` file trying to find how to specify the data field, but nothing seems to fit (based on the name)?

Am I on the right track? Would using `curl` be the right approach for my task, or should I be looking into some other C,C++ libraries? An example that does the same task as above `request.post()` is appreciated, or a suggestion how to achieve the same using `curl`.

Comment: Well it could but C based APIs are making things hard, and error prone. Do you loosely make HTTP request? You could just use the curl executable via stdin/out. Otherwise boost beast could be the thing you are looking for, if you need more control.

Comment: With curl, [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) is the equivalent to Python Requests' `data` parameter.

Comment: @drew010 thanks, it works, feel free to post it and I will accept it.